# How to change the hover effect for react-bootstrap navbar link?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

**I want to change the hover effect from white to green colour, but I cant sem to find the exact css code for it.**

```
<Navbar fixed='top' collapseOnSelect expand="md" variant="dark" className="animate-navbar nav-theme justify-content-between">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className='logo'>Anis Agwan</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#about">About Me</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#timeline">Timeline</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#skills">Skills</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
```

This is my CSS part

```
.nav-theme {
    background-color: #212121;
    font-size: 20px;
    
}

.animate-navbar {
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px hsla(240, 20%, 8%, 0.973);
   animation: moveDown 0.5s ease-in-out;
   
}


.logo {
  color: #64dd17;
}
```

Comment: Which element are you wanting to change the color on? Currently, there is no white element in your code.

Comment: I am trying to add hover effect on the nav links. i.e Home, About Me, etc. on the navbar

Comment: See the updated example, I used your code this time. - Just add a class to the nav links and change the colors there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some CSS that could help.

```css
.nav-links {
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
background-color:white;/*will change background-color of element */
color: green; /*will change color of text within the element */
}

.nav-links:hover {
background-color:green; /*will change background-color of element on hover */
color: white; /*will change color of text within the element on hover */
}
```

```html
<Navbar fixed='top' collapseOnSelect expand="md" variant="dark" class="navbar">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className='logo'>Anis Agwan</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Link class="nav-links" href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link class="nav-links" href="#about">About Me</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link class="nav-links" href="#timeline">Timeline</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link class="nav-links" href="#projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link class="nav-links" href="#skills">Skills</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link class="nav-links" href="#contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
```

Comment: Instead of background, I want the font color to change

Comment: I've updated my snippet and added comments. Let me know if that works.